# Magento2 - Product import extremely slow

Tags: magento2, import

I created a product (catalog) import module for magento2. I know there is a import module out of the box in magento2 but this does not serve my needs. All my data is stored in sepperate csv files (this data is updated hourly)

- articles.csv (7000 products)
- categories.csv
- attributes.csv
- article_attributes.csv

So all this data needs to be imported into magento2.

The import module is executed via the Index controller (mysite.url/import). This works fine and I can see that my products are being imported but it takes very long. After around 10mins I get a **504 Gateway Time-out error**

This is my code http://pastebin.com/t3z37X7a

How could I improve my code to reduce the execution time? Or should I try to work with Import classes from magento2 ?

Comment: Maybe better to process you csv file and convert it to magento format

Comment: By magento format you mean, convert it to one csv file that could be imported by magento ?

Comment: Yes, exectly. It's simplest way

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but is there a workaround on the max 2M file limit ? Magento gives me this message: Make sure your file isn't more than 2M.

Comment: This limit is minimum from php setting post_max_size and upload_max_filesize.

Comment: This limits is set also on the mysql parameter because magento import csv data into a import table.